# PHPMyAdmin 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: apache-2.2, rewrite, httpd.conf, 500-error

My home PHPMyAdmin was working fine a day or two ago.  Now it's giving me a generic 500 Internal Server Error and suggesting I look at my server logs.

The Apache log contains these error messages:

```
[Sun Feb 06 23:38:56 2011] [error] [client ::1] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

And this is where I get stuck.  Something is creating an infinite loop, but what can it be?  I haven't done anything (that I can think of) to my setup since PHPMyAdmin was last working.  Where would I follow the LimitInternalRecursion and LogLevel debug advice... an .htaccess file of some kind?  I don't know where to find that.

Can anyone offer any pointers towards a solution or course of action?

EDIT: Thanks to Alvosu I've been able to get some information from the Rewrite log:

```
::1 - - [07/Feb/2011:09:19:48 --0800] [localhost/sid#10080d720][rid#1009854a8/initial] (3) [perdir /Library/WebServer/Documents/] strip per-dir prefix: /Library/WebServer/Documents/pma/ -> pma/
::1 - - [07/Feb/2011:09:19:48 --0800] [localhost/sid#10080d720][rid#1009854a8/initial] (3) [perdir /Library/WebServer/Documents/] applying pattern '^$' to uri 'pma/'
::1 - - [07/Feb/2011:09:19:48 --0800] [localhost/sid#10080d720][rid#1009854a8/initial] (3) [perdir /Library/WebServer/Documents/] strip per-dir prefix: /Library/WebServer/Documents/pma/ -> pma/
::1 - - [07/Feb/2011:09:19:48 --0800] [localhost/sid#10080d720][rid#1009854a8/initial] (3) [perdir /Library/WebServer/Documents/] applying pattern '(.*)' to uri 'pma/'
::1 - - [07/Feb/2011:09:19:48 --0800] [localhost/sid#10080d720][rid#1009854a8/initial] (2) [perdir /Library/WebServer/Documents/] rewrite 'pma/' -> 'app/webroot/pma/'
::1 - - [07/Feb/2011:09:19:48 --0800] [localhost/sid#10080d720][rid#1009854a8/initial] (3) [perdir /Library/WebServer/Documents/] add per-dir prefix: app/webroot/pma/ -> /Library/WebServer/Documents/app/webroot/pma/
::1 - - [07/Feb/2011:09:19:48 --0800] [localhost/sid#10080d720][rid#1009854a8/initial] (2) [perdir /Library/WebServer/Documents/] strip document_root prefix: /Library/WebServer/Documents/app/webroot/pma/ -> /app/webroot/pma/
```

Can anyone interpret that to understand the problem for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LimitInternalRecursion will not help. Add [RewriteLog](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog) and [RewriteLogLevel](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteloglevel) directives in virtual host or server config(/etc/apache2/.. or /etc/httpd/.. for Linux). Then look rewrite log.

Comment: Hmm... I've added those directives into the httpd.conf file with what I think are sensible values (it's Linux by the way, MacOSX), but they don't seem to be doing anything that I can tell.  This is hard!

Comment: Do you restart Apache? If you gave virtual host, you need added directives to virtual host definition.

Comment: Good call!  As you can tell I'm a bit of a newbie.  I've upvoted you and edited my question with the contents of the Rewrite log - does that tell you what I need to go / where I need to go to kill this pma loop?

Comment: Um, okay, today my Rewrite log had completely new contents, which enabled me to work out that the following lines in my htaccess were creating an infinite loop: RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L], RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L].  Commenting them out seems to fix the problem.  I have no idea where they came from or whether they're meant to do anything useful.  But thanks for all your help in getting me on the right track!