# PHPMyAdmin - Error 500

Tags: apache-2.2, debian

Have scoured the board but can't seem to find anything that's helped yet.

If I go to http://localhost/ it's fine, if I go to http://localhost/phpmyadmin I get an 'Error 500: Internal Server Error'

There doesn't seem to be anything that'll show up in the log files either. I've tried the RewriteLog as mentioned in [PHPMyAdmin 500 Internal Server Error](https://serverfault.com/questions/232038/phpmyadmin-500-internal-server-error) - But that doesn't really seem to help either, nothing gets written to it when I've got:

```
# Logfiles
ErrorLog  /home/www/beta.**.com/logs/error.log
CustomLog /home/www/beta.**.com/logs/access.log combined
RewriteLog /home/www/beta.**.com/logs/rewrite.log
RewriteLogLevel 9
```

I've tried uninstalling the package and re-installing it, but that's not helped either. Anyone got any other suggestions? I'm running Debian and Apache 2.

Comment: Further to this, I've been through index.php and it dies after loading the required file libraries.common.inc.php - Which subsequently dies after the following lines (Line 538):

/**
 * @global PMA_Config $_SESSION['PMA_Config']
 * force reading of config file, because we removed sensitive values
 * in the previous iteration
 */
$_SESSION['PMA_Config'] = new PMA_Config('./config.inc.php');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I resolved it by changing Line 538 to the full path, I.E. /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php - Not 100% sure why, but it does.

Comment: In your config, you used `./config.inc.php` which takes the file from the current directory - and doesn't do any searching. When you change that to the full path, then PHP knows where to find it. Also: since we can't see your configuration file, *line 538* is meaningless.

Comment: Line 538 was this line:
$_SESSION['PMA_Config'] = new PMA_Config('./config.inc.php');

I'm aware that it'll just take it from the current directory, it just seems weird that a fresh out of the box install oh PHPMyAdmin would use that path.. Presumably the PMA_Config function should do something with the path which it wasn't necessarily doing..

Answer (score -1):

I faced  this  problem  in  localhost  and  I  tried to do many things to solve this problem and  I figure out  that  I had to uninstall  server and re-install it and everything works fine now.

Before you uninstall server copy all the database from here C:\server\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\data to save  folder. Because after the new install  he  will  remove all  the old database  because it removes the  old phpmyadmin and put a new one.
I know  this reply is late  but i want to give some help.

Comment: OP does not mention WAMP anywhere in the question..

Comment: sorry i did not  mean it  i will remove it  now